# how about selecting children in children in children... less big

Tags: javascript

what am i making?
i'm making a chrome extension for fun and the code below works completely fine, only...

i'm trying to resolve how i would be able to loop all of this so i dont have to write infinite code for every single child of a child that extends on a page.

```js
let stack = document.body.children;
for (let i = 0; i < stack.length; i++){
    stack[i].setAttribute("style", "border-radius:30px;");
    let stack2 = stack[i].children;
    for (let a = 0; a < stack2.length; a++) {
        stack2[a].setAttribute("style", "border-radius:30px;");
        let stack3 = stack2[a].children;
        for (let b = 0; b < stack3.length; b++) {
            stack3[b].setAttribute("style", "border-radius:30px;");
            let stack4 = stack3[b].children;
            for (let c = 0; c < stack4.length; c++) {
                stack4[c].setAttribute("style", "border-radius:30px;");
                let stack5 = stack4[c].children;
                for (let d = 0; d < stack5.length; d++) {
                    stack5[d].setAttribute("style", "border-radius:30px;");
                    let stack6 = stack5[d].children;
                    for (let e = 0; e < stack6.length; e++) {
                        stack6[e].setAttribute("style", "border-radius:30px;");
                        let stack7 = stack6[e].children;
                        for (let f = 0; f < stack7.length; f++) {
                            stack7[f].setAttribute("style", "border-radius:30px;");
                            let stack8 = stack7[f].children;
                            for (let g = 0; g < stack8.length; g++) {
                                stack8[g].setAttribute("style", "border-radius:30px;");
                                let stack9 = stack8[g].children;
                                for (let h = 0; h < stack9.length; h++) {
                                    stack9[h].setAttribute("style", "border-radius:30px;");
                                    let stack10 = stack9[h].children;
                                    for (let j = 0; j < stack10.length; j++) {
                                        stack10[j].setAttribute("style", "border-radius:30px;");
                                        let stack11 = stack10[j].children;
                                        for (let k = 0; k < stack11.length; k++) {
                                            stack11[k].setAttribute("style", "border-radius:30px;");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("*")` ?

Comment: Or alternatively, research "recursion" to avoid having to create a massive NodeList of matching elements (although the massive NodeList is probably fine for most pages; even with the JavaScript spec's 160k elements, building the NodeList only takes 9ms on Chrome ).

Comment: worked, was expecting it would be an easy outcome, but thanks none the less

Comment: final code:
`js
let stack = document.body.querySelectorAll("*");
for (let i = 0; i < stack.length; i++){
    stack[i].setAttribute("style", "border-radius:30px;");
}
`

Comment: Or in CSS : `* { border-radius:30px; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think recursive iteration is what you are looking for:

```
function drillDown(element) {
  if (element.hasChildNodes()) {
   for (let item of element.children) {
     if (!(item instanceof HTMLScriptElement || item instanceof HTMLHeadElement)) {
         drillDown(item);
         item.style.borderRadius = "30px";
     }
   }
  }
}
```

so you can traverse element's nodes tree like:

```
const root = document.querySelector('#root');
drillDown(root)
```

Comment: thanks, this works.
i have tried an even shorter method which also works:
`js
let stack = document.body.querySelectorAll("*"); for (let i = 0; i < stack.length; i++){     stack[i].setAttribute("style", "border-radius:30px;"); }
` but thanks none the less